# CreateML won't accept float64?

Tags: python, pandas, createml

I am trying out Create ML for the first time and I am trying to use a CSV file. Problem is that the CSV column for the target is a float type. It only accepts int or string. So, I used pandas to convert the column to a string with:

```
df.pris_yrs = df.pris_yrs.astype(str)

# I have also tried

df.pris_yrs = df.pris_yrs.apply(str)
```

Checking the dtype of the dataframe returns an object which is also a string in Pandas, but Create ML still is having the same error.

Question: How do I get an a dataframe object to work as the target in Create ML?

Answer (score 0):

To transform one column of a dataframe to `int` I recommend you:

```
df["pris_yrs "]=df["pris_yrs "].astype(int)
```

For every ML model you should use numerical targets (even if you have a categorical feature, you can transform it easily labelling it).

You obtain an error probably because your ML model don't support a string as a target.

Comment: The problem with that solution would be it would completely wreck the data making it not the same. I guess the better question would be how can I use a pandas object in Create ML?

Comment: You have an strange situation, why you want to change int to string? Which ML algorithm are you using?

Comment: I believe I have found a way to do it with the quoting parameter for to_csv in pandas. Docs specifically say that this should be used when you have floating point numbers.